# Use GCM rather than FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push

I still using Eclipse for development. I used to use GCM for push notification and just realised that Google introduced FCM while ago. I have problem to setup FCM jar files on Eclipse. Tried to use Google's Youtube video on Github to import libraries but still have problem with that and I prefer to get back to GCM if it is still available. I searched but didn't find the GCM Console anymore. Just wonder if anyone know what can I do ??

Comment: What's keeping you from using FCM? Other than you still just use Eclipse?

Comment: @AL. I followed http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2016/11/eclipse-integrate-firebase-analytics.html but still have problem on setup FCM for Eclipse. All videos and tutorials are just for Android Studio and can't understand how to use FCM on Eclipse

Comment: have you still ridden on a horse?

Comment: there are lots of problems you cannot solve with discontinued ADB for eclipse. so move to AS

Comment: @Rudi As I am still using `GCM` in some `eclipse` projects, I don't understand why you can't and what is your problem. Do you want to know how to get `GCM` libraries for your use or have problem creating a new `api-key` and `projectId`? Please update you question to clarify the problem.

Comment: @akramShokri thanks for your replay. I don't access to GCM Consul anymore ! Do you have the access ?

Comment: @Rudi I didn't use GCM console because I created the projects before and I just need `api-key (server-key)` and `projectId (senderId)` which I have. For your case, you can create a project in `FCM console` and still use the `server-key` and `projectId` inside your project with `GCM` libraries because they are compatible with eachother.

Comment: @Rudi I checked google-console and it is still accessible. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that you can still use google-console. 
Go to this link to create a new project or see `projectId` of available projects: https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/

Then you can add `credentials` for this project or you can go to this link to see availabe projects and their credentials: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/

You will see something similar to below image. In yellow box you can choose your project name. You can create a new credential by choosing the blue box.

[image: image-1]

Also note that you can choose your key to be unrestricted which gives you the liberty to use it in different applications, or you can restrict it to be more secure.

[image: image-2]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can create new projects with GCM.

I recently setup an app with push notifications but I was unable to use `GCM` and had to create a new `Firebase` project to be able to use `FCM`

Comment: Hi. Just to comment on the part where *GCM is deprecated*. There is still no official statement that GCM is deprecated (see [GCM FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq)), however (as you already mentioned) it is required that you have a Firebase Project instead of the normal Developer Console Project in order to use GCM (for the Server Key). Cheers!

Comment: OK technically it's not officially deprecated, but you can't create new GCM keys and existing users are being advised to update.